# XLM storage on hardware wallets Ledger Nano S vs Ledger Blue

Tags: xlm, ledger-nano, ledger-blue

How comes that Ledger Nano S supports XLM and Ledger Blue does not? Has it something to do with Stellar or Ledger because there should not be a difference which Ledger you use for safe storage of crypto.
We could use stellar desktop client, stargazer, lobstr and so on instead i get it. It is just to understand the WHY.

Answer (score 5):

Ledger Blue support is about to be released. The only reason the Ledger Blue was not supported until now is simply that it requires work and nobody had done it until now. But it will be available in the next weeks. You will be able to use the Ledger Blue on all Stellar wallets that have Ledger Nano S support.

Comment: That is good to hear. I can understand that Ledger Blue support is not a high priority thing. I am not a tech guy and when it comes to programming i am totally useless but isn't that a more or less copy/paste from one Ledger to the other? How many hours of work does it require approximately?